# Undefined reference to 'explain_setsocket'

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference

socket() function used in my code returns -1. Inorder to know more about it example_socket() is added and add headerfile

```
#include<libexplain/socket.h>
```

While compiling -lexplain is also added. But i have below error

> undefined reference to `explain_socket'

Code:

```
#include <libexplain/socket.h>
main(){
int sock;
if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1){
              char message[5000];
        memset(message,0,5000);
                printf("\nSOCKET ERROR\n");
        printf("err: socket() failed");
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", explain_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

---

[update [from comment]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892524/undefined-reference-to-explain-setsocket/45893665#comment78745092_45892524)

Compilation command:

```
cc xyz.c -lexplain -o xyz
```

Comment: What are `sopcket.h` and `example_socket`?

Comment: Why not just `if ((sock = ...) == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "err: socket() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno)); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`?

Comment: Show the actual compilation command. The order of arguments to the compiler (like `gcc`) matters a lot.

Comment: @melpomene i got socket() error during long run so i will try your solution

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch compilation command :cc xyz.c -lexplain -o xyz

Comment: That should go into your question. What compiler, operating system (and version) are you using? BTW,  enable all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....)

Answer (score 0):

> Compilation command:
>
> ```
> cc xyz.c -lexplain -o xyz
> ```

You might like to specify libraries last on the command line:

```
cc xyz.c -o xyz -lexplain
```

Comment: code is a part of a big program. Create a make file for compilation.